# Call function for some time and than call another function - NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, nstimer

I have two functions. I want to call first function for example - 60 seconds and than call second function. How to do it with NSTimer? Thanks.

Comment: The docs on `Timer` (`NSTimer`) are quite good. Did you try reading about the `Timer` class in the Xcode help system? Did you try writing some code yourself? If so, you should post your code here and tell us how it failed to meet your needs. If not, you should do so before posting questions on SO.

Comment: I didn't know, where to put NSTimer, Axel's answer help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
func firstFunction() {

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(secondFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
func secondFunction() {

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I have problem with first function. When NSTimer call second function. First function still running. How to stop it? Thanks.

Comment: No, firstFunction will run once and only once, and will take less than a microsecond to run. The only reason firstFunction would run again is if you called it again

Comment: I found it. It's because I have spawning skspritenodes and action is set to forever. Is there any solution how to continuously go to second function? Setting count to runaction is not optional.